# Does anyone know what I can find to edit code in dll, that works like jetBrains dotPeek, I need something that can allow me to edit the dll not view

Tags: dll

I found out what I needed but I can't find a way to install it or find any way to edit my file. I tried Visual Studio but it will not compile back because it finds errors is there a secondary method to break compilation of a dll file or bypass the errors visual studio is providing me so I can continue to decompile my dll and recompile it?

Visual studio gives 395 errors and prevents me from rebuilding the dll file. I am stuck at the wall blocking the bridge, all I need is a program that allows me to edit code in a dll file and I can't even find that.